# How do I run a function on multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a database of ~96000 people that I am trying to match to another similar database. Some are missing ID numbers so I need to match columns, however the data is a bit messy and contains trailing spaces and strange capitalizing of letters.

I am using `trimws()` and `capatalizeStrings()` from the *BBmisc package*. But only know how to run these on individual named columns eg

```
MDB$City<- capitalizeStrings(MDB$City,lower.back = T,all.words = T)

MDB$City<-trimws(MDB$City,which="both")
```

Is there an easier way to run these functions on every column in MDB that contains character data?

Comment: You can use `lapply` i.e. `MDB[nm1] <- lapply(MDB[nm1], function(x) trimws(capitalizeStrings(x, lower.back = TRUE, all.words = TRUE), "both"))` where `nm1 <- c("City", "OtherColumn1", ...)`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply`to loop over multiple columns and then assign the output back to the subset of dataset

```
MDB[nm1] <- lapply(MDB[nm1], function(x)
     trimws(capitalizeStrings(x, lower.back = TRUE, all.words = TRUE), "both"))
```

where

```
nm1 <- c("City", "OtherColumn1", "column2") #change the column names accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `dplyr::mutate_if`. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

MDB %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws(which = "both"))
```